# Отправка локального GET запроса из клиента

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

У меня есть приложение **ASP.NET Core Web API**, я не хочу деплоить его в общий доступ, вместо этого я хочу запустить его локально (через dotnet, на VDS, Ubuntu 16.04), что бы он был доступен по адресу: *http//localhost...*

Использовать данное API я хочу в JavaScript: пользователь нажимает на кнопку и отсылается GET запрос.

**Сам вопрос:**

Возможно-ли как-то отослать GET запрос из клиентской части на локальный хост

> Я понимаю, что JavaScript исполняется на стороне клиента и врятли получится такое сделать, но в JavaScript я новичок, по этому решил уточнить:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут язык программирования вообще не имеет значения. Большинство фронтенд-приложений собирается у клиента на компьютере и запросы улетают с его компьютера. Значит чтобы этот запрос дошёл до вашего бэкенда он должен быть общедоступен. Но есть вариант с SSR (Server side rendering). Отличие таких приложений от других в том, что сначала выполняются все запросы и собирается html и только потом результат отправляется клиенту. Но почти все из таких приложений в любом случае обращаются к API. В ходе работы. Допустим у пользователя отобразилась страница, которая была собрана и далее он хочет сделать какое-либо действие, например смотрит уведомления. А вам нужно теперь отметить это уведомление как прочитанное. Перерисовывать из-за этого всю страницу глупо, правильнее просто отправить запрос к API.

Странное решение закрывать бэкенд. Не думаю что из этого получится что-то толковое, он должен быть общедоступен

Comment: Спасибо, на счёт отрисовки страгицы - ничего страшного, у меня проект для универа)))))